# Work required to pump water out of a tank in the shape of a right circular cone

Tags: calculus, integration

A tank in the shape of a right circular cone is full of water. The tank is 6ft. across the top and 8 ft. high. How much work is done in pumping water over the top edge.

(a) Set up the integral

(b) Solve using the graphing calculator.

I only need help with part (a). My professor gave the answer in class but I can't seem to get my answers to match. Her answer is: 4929

$$Water: 62.4 lb/ft^3$$
$$Radius: 3ft$$
$$Height: 8ft$$
$$\frac38 = \frac xy => x=\frac38y$$
$$w = \int_0^8 \pi x^2 dy (62.4)(8-y)$$
$$w = 62.4 \pi \int_0^8 \left({\frac38y} \right)^2(8-y)dy$$

Then I plug that into calculator. My answer is 1323.2 Which is wrong. I know my integral isn't set up correctly. So if you can help me out.

Comment: As a start, define x and also y clearly first.

Comment: x is $\frac38y$. What do you mean define x? I substituted x into the integral.

Comment: I mean what does x represent. Is it radius? height? amount of water pumped out? What about y?

Comment: Your integral appears to be set up correctly.  When you evaluate it, I think you get $(62.4\pi)(48)$.

Comment: @Mick x represents the radius and Y is the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot get the specified answer also. My way of interpret it is:-

[image]

(1) Set up a representative disc as shown. It should be clear that its volume is $πx^2(dy)$.

(2) At that instant, $x = (3/8)y$.

(3) To empty all the water out, integrate $\int_0^8 πx^2(dy)$.

(4) Work done = 62.4 times the result of (3) and I got 4705.

Note:- If work done is equal to rate times amount of water, then it is equal to $62.4 [(1/3) π 3^2 (8)]$ directly.

Comment: ummm, the original question had a multiplier for height, (8-y), which is required for these kinds of work questions.

Comment: Although, the integral has dy, which is correct, he integrates w.r.t. dx.  With all due respect, this answer has two significant mistakes.